# Adding Aspx Page to Static Website

Tags: php, asp.net, html

We have a static website with all html files.

We have one more website which is developed in ASPX. This Dynamic Website has a Page (Say RegisterAndBuy.aspx) which populates some data based on user choice of Year etc, This page also Reads user's personal details and when submitted sends an email to the Admin which contains all the user entered information.

Both the websites are different from one another and hosted on different providers.

Now we want to add RegisterAndBuy.aspx page in the static website. We want to use the same page in static website with some minor changes. (We don't want to redirect to Dynamic website).

**Is this possible ????? Please let me know.**

Another solution that I am thinking is to develop a new PHP page to do this, but we have some excel reading stuff from aspx page. Doing all this stuff from PHP is tedious.

Comment: Insufficient data. Site servers? Site configurations? etc.

Comment: Static site Hosted on BigRock, Dynamic on Winhost, this is a asp.net website. We wanted to implement one aspx in static site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and embed it onto the static site. Not a whole page but just the bit you need.

```
<iframe  src="RegisterAndBuy.aspx " title="RegisterAndBuy" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: So can I execute the functionality of aspx page on static webpage. As I asked earlier, the aspx page dynamically loads data from MS SQL DB based on user selection, We will change it to read from excel files while implementing on static website.

Comment: The situation where i used this is i had a form that collected users details hosted on another server and it needed to be added to a static website. So i iframed the form on a page of the static site allowing the user to fill it in a submit it from the static site.

Comment: Sounds good. So iframe src should be www.anothersite.com/RegisterAndBuy.aspx. When user submits the form the data is processed by the other website. Is this right ?

Comment: Yes. So in my case when the form is submitted it processes on the other site and responds with a success page in the iframe.

Comment: ok, Instead of redirecting it to other website, Is it possible to copy the same aspx page into the Static website server, this way we can do any other customizations to the Form also.

Comment: If the server is set-up to run aspx files then I don't see why not.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is possible for you or not because the server environment, configuration etc. is not specified.
But if possible you can create another ASP.NET website, get all the HTML pages in your website along with the "RegisterAndBuy.aspx" page, and with all referred DLLs. And then deploy it at your static website server.
This may solve your problem and reduce the rework.

Comment: Why downvote? While giving downvote, please mention the reason as well...

Comment: Suppose the server supports ASPX , then can we embed the required aspx.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum, don't know about down voting etc.

Comment: If your server supports ASPX, then fasted way would be to create a new web application in .NET and add existing static pages along with RegisterAndBuy.aspx.
Regarding downvote: forget it :)